# Atualizar sistema em Java Web

Tags: java

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou com a ideia de fazer um sistema com Java Web, mas estou começando a aprender java agora. Um amigo me disse contras de fazer com Java Web e disse para fazer em Python. Os argumentos contra o Java:

1 - Gera 1 arquivo só que onde todo mundo acessa ele, que contem toda a informação dos sistema inteiro.

2 - Para fazer uma atualização nele (sem chances de erro) precisaria fazer isso em um horário de nenhum acesso pois o mesmo demora para subir para o servidor e teria que reiniciar o serviço do servidor.

3 - O DNS demoraria de 3 a 7 horas para se atualizar com as informações novas.

4 - Empresas que utilizam Java Web estão migrando por ser mais difícil de se manter.

Esse problema de demorar para atualizar e o cliente ficar sem o sistema pode ser contornado?

Comment: Marcelo, acho muito difícil responder qualquer tipo de pergunta do tipo "O que é melhor do que o que" no formato do Stack Overflow. O ponto 1 é falso, o ponto 2 é resultado de uma má arquitetura, o ponto 3 não tem nada a ver com a linguagem de programação (se você atualizar uma entrada DNS de uma aplicação Python também precisará esperar o tempo de propagação) e o ponto 4 faz parte da vida (tem empresas mudando de linguagem X para Y e outras mudando da linguagem Y para a X, e finalmente tem empresas que não estão fazendo nenhuma das duas coisas).

Comment: Sei que não devo perguntar algo baseado em achismo. Coloquei os pontos sobre a questão de atualização, se realmente teria problemas e qual seria a solução para a questão de um possível atualização do software e o quanto o cliente seria prejudicado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Há muita coisa que poderia ser argumentada contra o Java, mas **NENHUM** desses quatro argumentos é verdadeiro. Eles nem sequer são versões distorcidas ou tendenciosas da realidade, são absolutamente e completamente falsos mesmo. São mentiras cabeludas.

Entretanto, vamos lá mesmo assim:

> 1 - Gera 1 arquivo só que onde todo mundo acessa ele, que contem toda a informação dos sistema inteiro.

Dê uma olhada nos pacotes [`java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) e [`java.io`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html), que contém classes que permitem escrever e ler dados de bases de dados SQL e de arquivos. Qualquer arquivo do sistema operacional pode ser acessado. Qualquer provedor de SQL pode ser utilizado. Logo, essa afirmação 1 é falsa.

Se no entanto o problema é que uma aplicação web é empacotada toda dentro de um único arquivo *.war* ou *.ear* para ser implantada no servidor, então não vejo porque isso seria um problema. Na verdade, considero isso uma vantagem! Desta forma, fica mais fácil garantir que todos os recursos necessários para a aplicação estão juntos e que nada está faltando, uma vez que tudo estará em um mesmo arquivo que poderá então ser distribuído ou implantado de forma muito mais fácil do que seria no caso de serem múltiplos arquivos. O mesmo vale também para bibliotecas ou programas *standalone* em Java que vem empacotados como *.jar*.

Os formatos de arquivo *.jar*, *.war* ou *.ear* nada mais são do que um arquivo *.zip* com uma extensão diferente e uma determinada organização interna (tanto que você pode facilmente renomear a extensão de qualquer um deles para *.zip* e então abrir ele para ver o seu conteúdo). Desta forma, todos os recursos que você quiser colocar dentro do *.jar*, *.war* ou *.ear* poderiam ser nele adicionados da mesma forma que você faria com um arquivo *.zip* (só que normalmente isso é feito pelo compilador, IDE ou alguma outra ferramenta de apoio, apenas muito raramente isso seria feito manualmente).

Se o seu programa que está empacotado em um *,jar*, *.war* ou *.ear* precisar acessar algum recurso que não foi empacotado junto, então basta usar o IO provido pelas classes do pacote `java.io` tal como já explanei acima, e você poderá acessar os arquivos do sistema operacional que quiser e como quiser.

Por fim, a abordagem de juntar vários recursos, em especial código compilado, para montar um arquivo executável (neste caso o executável é o *.jar*, *.war* ou *.ear*) não é muito diferente do que outras linguagens fazem para montar os respectivos executáveis (como por exemplo, *.exe* no Windows).

> 2 - Para fazer uma atualização nele (sem chances de erro) precisaria fazer isso em um horário de nenhum acesso pois o mesmo demora para subir para o servidor e teria que reiniciar o serviço do servidor.

Os principais servidores em Java da atualidade, tais como Tomcat, Glassfish, Jetty e Wildfly têm recursos de *hot deploy* e replicação para evitar *downtime*. Todos eles têm o recurso de permitir a implantação nos servidores sem precisar reiniciá-los.

Quanto a questão do "sem chances de erro", para qualquer servidor em qualquer linguagem de programação, se você subir uma versão errada e ela bagunçar com o seu sistema, isso daí não é culpa da linguagem de programação, e sim do pacote errado que você subiu ou então do desenvolvedor que o desenvolveu ou do implantador que o disponibilizou. Assim sendo, esse seria um problema que acontece igualmente com todas as linguagens de programação e com todos os tipos de servidores.

> 3 - O DNS demoraria de 3 a 7 horas para se atualizar com as informações novas.

O processo que atualiza o DNS (muitas vezes é um processo manual) não tem qualquer relação com a linguagem de programação ou com o tipo de servidor ou mesmo com a aplicação implantada no servidor. De fato, essas duas partes da infraestrutura nem sequer se comunicam diretamente entre si, e isso ocorre com todas as linguagens de programação e todos os servidores. A atualização do DNS é um processo completamente independente e desacoplado disso.

> 4 - Empresas que utilizam Java Web estão migrando por ser mais difícil de se manter.

Sempre há quem migre para fora quanto quem migre para dentro. Há muitas empresas por aí que o usam de forma pesada. Para dar exemplos concretos e não ficar só no falatório, posso citar o UOL, todas as operadoras de telefonia celular do Brasil, diversas instituições bancárias, redes de farmácias (como DrogaRaia e DrogaFarma), universidades, etc.

Observe que não digo que Java é a melhor coisa do mundo e de certo há um monte de problemas que poderiam ser criticados. Entretanto, as críticas aqui colocadas são simplesmente falsas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: @Marcelo De nada. :)

Comment: Acho que a primeira pergunta está falando de arquivos .war.

Comment: @Piovezan Editado. :D